# Shadow Mapping Wobble

Tags: graphics, directx, hlsl, shadows, shadow-mapping

Ive been researching omnidirectional shadow mapping and have been stuck on this problem for a while. Basically the shadows seem to wobble as the camera is moved or rotated. I made a video here:

http://youtu.be/w8IAdNPglAc

The problem is most visible about half way through on the gravestones at the bottom of the screen.

The project is implemented in a deferred renderer and at first i thought the problem was to do with aligning texels to pixels but i read that since directx 10 (which i'm using) this is no longer a problem. Someone also suggested that i was updating the camera after the render call so it was a frame behind but this is not the problem.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

I didn't want to start by posting massive amounts of code. If there is anything needed i can post it.

Comment: Did you read the article http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ee416324%28v=vs.85%29.aspx ? There are many issues described, including some wobble-artifacts, maybe it contains your problem.

Comment: I thought the part on shimmering shadow edges was going to solve it for me but it only provides a solution for directional lights and im using point lights :( But referring to it as shimmering instead of wobbling has proved promising in google...

Comment: Perhaps a problem with the resolution of your shadow map?

Comment: The problem persists no matter the resolution, ive ran it at 512, 1024, and 2048 and i still have the same problem